# Banyuwangi to Kawa Ijen by motorbike, possible?

Tags: transportation, indonesia, motorcycles, night-transport

I would like to avoid the packaged tours, and go to Kawa Ijen (Sempol) from Banyuwangi by motorbike (scooter).

This looks not only cheaper but also nicer and more fun.

My only concern is the state of the road. Not sure if this is doable during day time, even less during night time. Note that it's dark around 17:30 in Indonesia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### State of the road

The road from Banyuwangi to  Sempol is awesome.

The road is like new. There is tarmac all way to the entrance of the Kawa Ijen (national?) parc, there are very few potholes on the road (if any).

The reason for this, is that there is now a bicycle race called [Tour de Banyuwangi Ijen](http://tourdebanyuwangiijen.id), running every year since 2012 (or 2013?) so the road must be able to welcome racing bicycle!

---

#### Riding during the day

Extremely easy. Just take your time and you will reach the entrance of the parc in about 1h30min.

Enjoy the ride, it's a nice one, the road is great and the country side beautiful.

---

#### Riding during the night

Completely doable, it will just take a bit longer than if you do it during the day. You will also miss the view, but you'll have it on the way back I suppose.

I did this partly at night (the last third of the journey), and the only thing is that it gets pretty cold! It gets quite high, so cold too, make sure you bring some quality clothing (thermal clothes, and a jacket).

---

#### Renting a scooter in Banyuwangi

Extremely easy. Just contact one of the local motorbike renting companies and get yourself ready to go. I got in touch with one called [Tripoli Tour & Travel](http://goo.gl/maps/EAncY), I booked the scooter while in the train to Banyuwangi and it took 5 minutes to sort the paperwork when I came to their office. Was perfect.

Here are their details: Tripoli Tour and Travel, Jalan Basuki Rahmat No. 77, Banyuwangi, Jawa Timur 68414, Indonesia, http://goo.gl/maps/EAncY