# Ketapang/Banyuwangi to Mt. Ijen?

Tags: transportation, indonesia, volcanoes

Someone advised me to join the Ijen one-day tour package from Banyuwangi.
Are there more convenient alternatives from Ketapang to Ijen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kawah Ijen volcano at night](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30808/kawah-ijen-volcano-at-night)

Comment: I realise it's annoying when somebody makes a suggestion, you follow it and then somebody else complains.  But what is "convenient"? Something that's convenient for me might be very inconvenient for you, since convenience depends very much on personal circumstances and tastes.

Answer (score 1):

I am also traveling to Indonesia next month and the following information i gathered:

once you arrive in Banyuwangi it is possible to hire an ojek in Banyuwangi for the journey up to Kawah Ijen, have the ojek driver wait for you to climb up to the crater. The ojek can then to take you onwards to the bus terminal in Bondowoso or
can bring you back to  Banyuwangi again.
Also ojek can take you to first town on the way down from the crater that is serviced by public transport, Sempol.

There is another alternative route a bus from banuwangi to Licin village. From Licin you either charter a 4WD or a motorbike. If you rent a car in Banyuwangi to bring you to Paltuding it will cost you around IDR 550,000 - IDR 600,000. By motorbike it will be around IDR 200,000 - IDR 250,000.

Hope this will help and i would be visiting Ijen the opposite way from Bondowoso